# Variable that holds "list of all open buffers" in Vim?

Tags: vim

`:vimgrep` looks like a really useful thing.

Here's how to use it:

```
:vim[grep][!] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file} ...
```

`:help` says that you can essentially glob `{file}` to name, say, `*.c` for the current directory. I may have started Vim with a list of files that is complicated enough that I don't want to manually type it in for `{file}`, and besides Vim already knows what those files are.

What I would like to do is vimgrep over any of:

- `:args`
- `:files`
- `:buffers`

What variable(s) would I use in place of `{file}` to name, respectively, any of those lists in a `vimgrep` command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can't you catch the result in these commands into a register (`:h :redir`), and insert it back into `:vimgrep` call (with a `:exe`).

Something like:

```
:exe "vimgrep/pattern/ " . lh#askvim#Exe(':args')
```

Notes:

- [lh#askvim#Exe](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib#miscellaneous-functions) is just a wrapper around `:redir` ; nothing really complex
- some of these results may need some processing (see `:args` that adds square brackets)
- Sometimes there is a function that returns exactly what you are looking for, see `join(argv(), ' ')` in `:args` case
- Regarding :buffers, may be something like:

.

```
function BuffersList()
  let all = range(0, bufnr('$'))
  let res = []
  for b in all
    if buflisted(b)
      call add(res, bufname(b))
    endif
  endfor
  return res
endfunction
:exe 'vimgrep/pattern/ '.join(BuffersList(),' ')
```

Comment: BuffersList works exactly as I wanted. Thanks Luc and Zathrus.

Comment: This answer was helpful, but <a="http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=311">grep.vim</a> is a vim plugin that uses all variants of the system's grep programs, searches for the word under the cursor (by default), and can search files, args and open buffers.

Comment: You have a typo in the function definition for BuffersList. You have 3 f's instead of 2. Since it is only a single character change I cannot edit it. P.S. Nice answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
:bufdo vimgrep /pattern/ %
```

% substitutes the buffer name.

Comment: This is a great one-liner! I can't believe I didn't know about this years ago.

Answer (score 5):

To [vim]grep the list of files in the argument list, you may use `##` (see `:help cmdline-special`).

```
:vimgrep /re/ ##
```

I am unaware of a similar shorthand for the buffer list, but you may be able to do something like:

```
:argdelete ##
:bufdo argadd %
```

... and then use `##`.  Or use `:n` to open new files (which will be added to the arg list) instead of `:e`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly refined version of one of the answers. The following command searches for the pattern in all opened tabs and remembers results in quickfix list:

```
:cex [] | tabdo vimgrepa /pattern/ %
```

`cex []` sets contents of quickfix list to empty list. You need to call it first because `vimgrepa` accumulates search results from all the tabs. Also, you can replace `tabdo` with `argdo`, `bufdo` and `windo`.

To view search results execute:

```
:cope
```

This method, however, has limitation: it can only search in tabs which already have file names assigned to them (`%` would not expand in a new tab).

**EDIT:**
You can also shortcut the command into function in your `~/.vimrc` like this:

```
function TS(text)
    exe "cex [] | tabdo vimgrepa /" . a:text . "/ %"
endfunction
command -nargs=1 TS call TS(<q-args>)
cnoreabbrev ts TS
```

With last line you can call your function like this:

```
:ts from game import
```

where words after `ts` is a search pattern. Without last line you have to type function name in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful script !
A minor fix: The search finds one of the buffers twice - first time as the numbered buffer, second as buffer #0 => alternate buffer.
Hence, we shall change the line to "**range(1, bufnr('$'))**" to skip the alternate buffer and show the search results once.